# Avoid Deadlock During SSRS Reports Deployment

Tags: sql, powershell, reporting-services

I wonder if anyone has any suggestion or experience with the same scenario.

We have one Server we utilise for our SSRS Reports. We deploy to Multiple Folders in SSRS i.e. Site_1, Site_2, Site_3 ... Site_26

In each site we deploy roughly about 800+ Reports. These reports are the same for Site_1 to Site_26 (except if we skip a site).

We use Azure DevOps with Powershell ReportingServicesTools to deploy the reports.

What happens is when we start the deployment, we will get several sites failing due to a deadlock with the below error:

**The Report and Process ID is Random and never the same**

##[error]Failed to create  item Report.rdl : Failed to create catalog item C:\azagent\A9_work\r5\a\SSRS Reports\Reports\Report.rdl : Exception calling "CreateCatalogItem" with "7" argument(s): "System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: An error occurred within the report server database.  This may be due to a connection failure, timeout or low disk condition within the database. ---> Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.ReportServerStorageException: An error occurred within the report server database.  This may be due to a connection failure, timeout or low disk condition within the database. ---> **System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Transaction (Process ID 100) was deadlocked on lock resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim.** Rerun the transaction.

The error is not related to Low Disk etc as we've tested this to death and it occurs with two sites on a monster server. The error is Transaction Deadlock.

The only way we can successfully deploy the reports is if we deploy them concurrently one after the other. However, due to time constraints and business requirements this is not an option.

We have done all the PSSDiags etc and found that the error occurs due to this Stored Procedure "FindObjectsNonRecursive"

We nearly resolved it by adding the (NoLock) option but it seems this was only temporary and we're back to where we were. Microsoft also advised that they would not change it. Also noting that 18 months down the line MS still has not been able to give us a fix or a solution to our problem.

I would appreciate any feedback from anyone on how you overcame this problem if you had it.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

> I would appreciate any feedback from anyone on how you overcame this problem if you had it.

Did you try retrying like the error suggests?  Deadlocks are timing-dependent, so it should eventually succeed.

Comment: Hi David,

It will work if I retry. However, it defeats the purpose of CI/CD. We have 30+ sites, that basically means I have to site there and retry the whole night.

Comment: Can’t you automate the retry or deploy the folders one at a time?